# Why is Kernel Density Estimation failing to find bandwidth?

Tags: distributions, kernel-smoothing

I am computing multivariate kernel density estimations on subsets of data in MATLAB. I have successfully done the KDEs with 47 different datasets of 45 points (each has an X and Y coordinate). But when I use small subsets, such as 7 or 8 points (again, each has an X and Y coordinate) I am getting an error that the code cannot find a bandwidth that fits the data.

From what I understand about the research looking at variance and reliability of KDEs, it should be able to handle such a low sample size.

Below is an example of the X and Y coordinates I am using:

```
1594436.281 572258.1272
1594418.48  572357.5859
1594471.362 572385.5186
1594516.726 572266.8206
1594415.313 572369.2754
1594519.701 572272.7153
1594415.377 572363.4139
1594468.365 572381.5779
1594518.139 572276.6059
1594425.496 572271.6874
```

I would like to understand how a bandwidth is not being generated and possible other problems with this method.

I am using the following algorithm (in MATLAB). Each point has an X and Y coordinate, like the above example. Each of these points has a time stamp of real numbers starting from 1 to n. A time window is established that is Z in size and increments in a step wise pattern. In other words, the time window starts from 1 to Z and increments to 2 to Z + 1. Any of the points that fit within the time window are used for the KDE at that time window. A typical size of the time window is 14. So that would cover 1 to 14 (Z = 14). A typical number of time windows for a dataset is 45. So that would be 1 to 45 (n = 45). That means there is a KDE for time windows 1 - 14, 2 - 15, ... 32 - 45. This is the [KDE code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17204-kernel-density-estimation/content/kde2d.m) I am using.

The error I am getting is that fzero cannot find a root between 0 and 0.1. Unless I am mistaken, this means that the data doesn't sample an underlying distribution sufficiently well for a bandwidth to be found. I would assume the 'best' (or 'easiest'?) data for a bandwidth to be found in KDE would be normally distributed with high sample size. My data is clumped in almost island like formations and is very low sample size (example I gave is 10 points).

Comment: In order for this question to be answerable you will need to edit it to include information about the algorithm your code is using.

Comment: @whuber Understood. Further information is provided.

Comment: For your small subsets, how many points are found in the time windows?  (I am wondering whether the problem might be that one or more of those windows contains only one point, which would preclude any bandwidth estimation.)

Comment: I account for that. Can only compute if at least 3 points. The subset I provided is an example of the points within one of the time windows. There are 45 points total and each time window has some subset of those 45 points. What is really interesting is that I did KDEs in R using intervals of 5 points (5, 10, ... 45) and NEVER had a bandwidth NOT be found (i.e. No crash). This is really really puzzling me.

Comment: And actually...there was an issue before with this KDE code when there was a replicate in the dataset. Computing a bandwidth failed. But, when I manually changed one of the replicates (e.g. + 0.0000001) it ran 'flawlessly'. I did not think about any relationship between that problem and this...but who knows? That's why I'm asking!